# How do I send Microsoft Office Mime Types as Content-Type header with with Spring Boot RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, ms-office

I'm building a microservice with Java 8 and SpringBoot,
it is to have the folowing flow -

1. A file will come in, with a GUID as a name and no file extension.
2. Another xml file will come in containing the file type eg/ xslx
3. The file type is scraped from the xml
4. The *file is then sent out on an Http POST with the body as the file payload
   and a header 'Content-Type' containing the mime-type.

*All MS Office document types are to be supported - https://www.askingbox.com/info/mime-types-of-microsoft-office-file-formats
22 different mime-types are listed there.

I've added a custom MessageConverter to my RestTemplate -

> ```
> MediaType mt = new MediaType("application", "vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
> List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<>();
> ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter converter = new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter();
> converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Collections.singletonList(mt));
> messageConverters.add(converter);
> restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);
> ```

The problem is Spring AFAIK does not support any of those types, so MediaType.ALL will not cover them.
So as soon as I add something like

```
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template
```

as a Content-Type Header,
Spring complains:

```
No HttpMessageConverter for sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream and content type "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
```

Does anybody have an idea on how I can get Spring to behave and accept the MS mime types : https://www.askingbox.com/info/mime-types-of-microsoft-office-file-formats

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `HttpMessageConverter` converts between byte data and some Java object. As such, it needs to understand both the byte data *and* the Java object type. The format of the byte data is given as a mime type.

An `HttpMessageConverter` can e.g. indicate that it supports `application/xml` and the `Document` DOM type, and would use a DOM parser when converting in one direction, and an XSLT copy transformation when converting in the other direction.

Another `HttpMessageConverter` could then indicate that it supports `application/xml` and a POJO type that's been annotated with `@XmlRootElement`, and would use JAXB to convert, in both directions.

As you can see, both the mime type and the Java type is important to the `HttpMessageConverter`.

The error message in the question identifies both the mime type and the Java type:

- Mime type: `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`
- Java type: `sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream`

The problem is that although your custom message converter has been configured to say it supports the mime type in question, you used the `ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter`, and it only supports `byte[]` as the Java type *(see name of message converter class)*.

Since the Java type is `ChannelInputStream`, that custom message converter is not applicable, and since there is no other message converter that supports the mime/java type combination, you get that error.

I see two fairly easy solutions:

1. Load the data from the `ChannelInputStream` into a `byte[]`, then send that instead of the `ChannelInputStream` object.
2. Change the custom message converter to be a `ResourceHttpMessageConverter`, then wrap the `ChannelInputStream` object in an `InputStreamResource` when sending. This will stream the data, using less memory. *(Recommended)*